# Export text and image in the same file

Tags: ios, objective-c, export, rtf

What I want to do is exporting some data from my app to a text file - say an RTF file. I found that converting text can be done through [this](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/RTF) classes, but is there a way to save an image also?

Comment: Why not export to PDF?

Comment: I don't know, I have searched around a little and writing to a PDF seems overly complicated. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AlessandroRoaro writing to a PDF file can seem complicated at once, but Apple provides the tools in Quartz 2D. Look at my answer for some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export text + images in the same document you can do it usig Core Graphics. Please search for **CGPDFDocument Reference** and **Quartz 2D Programming Guide** in Apple documentation.

However in order to do this you need to have an understanding of the PDF format and you should read the Adobe guide **PDF Reference**, Fourth Edition, Version 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Using [CGPDFContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html) you can create a `UIView`, draw your contents into it (using sub views to make life easy for text and images) and then render the views `layer` into the PDF context. Then save the resulting data to a file.